# Cronjob not running php document

Tags: php, shell, cron

I have a cronjob calling a shell script. Inside that shell script and I have these lines:

```
php backup.php
(cat db-backup.sql ; uuencode db-backup.sql db-backup.sql) | mailx -s 'Database Daily Backup' mail@mail.com
rm -f db-backup.sql
```

When I run this shell script manually like this ./backup it creates a backup file of database, sends me an email and deletes the file. When cron calls this script It sends me a blank e-mail and it does not call/run the php file properly. What could be the cause of this problem?

Note: both shell script and php file has -rwxr-xr-x perms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cron` is probably not executing the script in a directory where your user account has write permissions. (On my system, `ls -l /proc/$(pidof cron)/cwd` shows the current working directory is `/var/spool/cron/`.)

Put an explicit `cd /path/to/writable/directory` immediately before the `php` line.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Excellent. Don't overlook [Alex's advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10008652/377270), it is all too often the cause of `cron` problems. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use full paths when creating cron scripts. For example:

```
/usr/bin/php-cli backup.php
```